# jqGrid: Filter for empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, filter

I have created a example where it displayes the filter textboxes in the header, but when I enter nothing in the input, the filter is simply not applied.

Also if I generate a dropdown and say ":Empty values" all elements are shown and not just the empty elements.

Any examples how to filter for empty with inputs or dropdown filters in jqGrid?

BR,
Stefan

Comment: filtering in `toolbar search`?

Comment: yes, I want to use the filters form the toolbar search, as shown in this example: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe.htm